# Is there a Windows Explorer integration for JFrog Artifactory?

Tags: windows, artifactory

I am looking for an integration of JFrog Artifactory into the Windows Explorer, my idea is something like "TortoiseArtifactory". Does anyone know of such a possibility?

Answer (score 2):

Artifactory does not have such a tool AFAIK.

For some integration with the Windows Explorer:

- Follow [Artifactory WebDav documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Using+WebDAV) to see its capabilities.
- See how to use [WebDav in Windows Explorer](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/216473357-Accessing-WebDAV-with-Windows) and see if it provides your needs.